# Question on Taylor's PDE, Volume 2, Problem 8.4.10

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

This is probably a very trivial question but I think I'm just confusing myself. To compute the integral:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma\frac{dz}{z^{k+1}\sqrt{1-2tz+z^2}},$$
Taylor says to "use the change of variable $1-uz=\sqrt{1-2tz+z^2}$" in order to apply Cauchy's theorem. I haven't been able to make this work out in any nice way, however. Obviously $u$ must depend on $z$; we're effectively taking the substitution:
$$u(z)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2tz+z^2}}{z}.$$
However solving for $z$, substituting and dividing by the differential $du/dz$, and simplifying everything just seems to make the integral more complicated, so I must be overthinking how this substitution is supposed to work.

Comment: Just to state it explicitly, what's the nature of the contour $\Gamma$?

Comment: @CadeReinberger Not given explicitly in the hint, but it just needs to be a simple closed curve containing $0$ (avoiding the branch cut of the square root, but $t>0$ so that should be possible).